# calculating the total time for each event based on the first and last of each unique record pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a  pandas dataframe as shown below:

```
  event_id           timestamp
0       e0 2015-07-20 12:00:56
1       e0 2015-07-20 13:00:56
2       e1 2015-07-20 01:30:00
3       e1 2015-07-20 02:30:00
4       e1 2015-07-20 03:00:00
5       e2 2015-07-20 18:45:00
6       e2 2015-07-20 18:47:00
7       e2 2015-07-20 18:48:00
8       e2 2015-07-20 18:49:00
```

I want to calculate the total time for each event to produce:

```
                   timestamp  count (minutes)
event_id                                     
e0       2015-07-20 13:00:56             60.0
e1       2015-07-20 03:00:00             90.0
e2       2015-07-20 18:49:00              4.0
```

Comment: Please post your dataframe as text

Comment: Thank you everyone its the first time i have posted something and amazing response. Thank you community....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `agg`

```
s = df.groupby('event_id').timestamp.diff().div(pd.Timedelta(minutes=1))

df.assign(minutes=s).groupby('event_id').agg({'timestamp': 'last', 'minutes': 'sum'})
```

```
                   timestamp  minutes
event_id
e0       2015-07-20 13:00:56     60.0
e1       2015-07-20 03:00:00     90.0
e2       2015-07-20 18:49:00      4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Recreating your dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['e0','2015-07-20 12:00:56'],
    ['e0','2015-07-20 13:00:56'],
    ['e1','2015-07-20 01:30:00'],
    ['e1','2015-07-20 02:30:00'],
    ['e1','2015-07-20 03:00:00'],
    ['e2','2015-07-20 18:45:00'],
    ['e2','2015-07-20 18:47:00'],
    ['e2','2015-07-20 18:48:00'],
    ['e2','2015-07-20 18:49:00']],
    columns=['event_id','timestamp'])
```

You can use `sort_values()` to ensure that the `timestamp` column is sorted for each group in `event_id`. Then you can leverage `groupby()` and `apply()` with `pd.Timedelta()` to calculate the difference in time between each entry (or row):

```
df['count (minutes)'] = df.sort_values(['event_id','timestamp']).groupby('event_id')['timestamp'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.iloc[0])/pd.Timedelta(1, 'm'))
```

Which gives:

```
  event_id           timestamp  count (minutes)
0       e0 2015-07-20 12:00:56              0.0
1       e0 2015-07-20 13:00:56             60.0
2       e1 2015-07-20 01:30:00              0.0
3       e1 2015-07-20 02:30:00             60.0
4       e1 2015-07-20 03:00:00             90.0
5       e2 2015-07-20 18:45:00              0.0
6       e2 2015-07-20 18:47:00              2.0
7       e2 2015-07-20 18:48:00              3.0
8       e2 2015-07-20 18:49:00              4.0
```

Then you can call `groupby()` once more and return the last row using `last()`:

```
df.groupby('event_id').last()
```

Yields:

```
                   timestamp  count (minutes)
event_id                                     
e0       2015-07-20 13:00:56             60.0
e1       2015-07-20 03:00:00             90.0
e2       2015-07-20 18:49:00              4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using groupby without sorting,

```
df.groupby('event_id').timestamp.agg(['last', lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).total_seconds() / 60.0])\
.rename(columns = {'last': 'timestamp','<lambda>': 'count (minutes)'}).reset_index()


    event_id    timestamp             count (minutes)
0   e0          2015-07-20 13:00:56   60.0
1   e1          2015-07-20 03:00:00   90.0
2   e2          2015-07-20 18:49:00   4.0
```